# Change the index symbol of a FormalPowerSeries in Sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

If I construct a `FormalPowerSeries` of an expression, the default symbol used as an indexing variable is `k`. This is not an inherent problem, but I'd like to adhere to the conventions of other formal texts where `n` is used.

```
from sympy.series.formal import FormalPowerSeries, fps
gfps: FormalPowerSeries = fps(1/(1-z))
display(gfps)

# Workaround utility to find the first dummy with a given name
def findDummy(expr: Expr, name: str) -> Dummy:
    from sympy.utilities.iterables import default_sort_key
    return next(filter(
        lambda s: isinstance(s, Dummy) and s.name == name,
        sorted(expr.free_symbols, key=default_sort_key)))

# Workaround, replace the dummy `k` with another dummy, `n`
form = (gfps.ak.formula * gfps.xk.formula)
k: Dummy = findDummy(gfps, 'k')
gfps = gfps.xreplace({k: Dummy('n', integer=True)})
display(gfps)
```

The first call to `display` yields the following
[image: geometric series with term z indexed by k]
when i would prefer to have
[image: geometric series with term z indexed by n].
While I could construct an instance of `Sum` from the `form` variable, I'd prefer to keep the semantics of a `FormalPowerSeries` datatype. My current workaround works for toy problems, but I am uncertain yet if it breaks any of the underlying machinery or if there is a canonical way to perform this re-indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `xreplace` is a valid way to change a symbol in an expression.